# I need help creating a one click hide and show link

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a couple layers on a page and switch the between layers in one click.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you encounter problems? This is not a difficult task. Stack Overflow does not write code for you.

Comment: [jQuery-UI's Tab Control?](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery and tooggleClass() function, by applying this to "click" event.
For example:

```
$('#button').click( function () {
    $('#layer1').toggleClass('classToShow');
    $('#layer2').toggleClass('classToShow');
    $('#layer3').toggleClass('classToShow');
});
```

And at start only one from layers has the class "classTShow".

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jquery:

```
document.getElementById('name').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('name').style.display = ""; //show
```

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` is the CSS property which defines the vertical position of an element. The elements with the highest `z-index` values are on top. You can use this to create layers.

Then, just create a `click` event for your layer buttons, and change the `z-index`:

```
document.getElementById('layer1').style.zIndex = '10'
```

If you are talking about *tabs*, then [jarrett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176458/i-need-help-creating-a-one-click-hide-and-show-link/5176471#5176471) should be the one to look at.

Comment: I think it says something about how poorly the question is written that we are offering totally different answers and either one could be what they are looking for.

Comment: Questions these days are *really* ambiguous, and kind of annoying to constantly flag. **HELPME NAOW!!!!1!**

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery.

You can select elements on your page and control their visibility easily.

HTML:

```
<div class="layer" id="layer1">
 stuff in here for layer 1
</div>
<div class="layer" id="layer2" style="display:none">
 stuff in here for layer 2
</div>
<p id="button">click me</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('.layer').toggle();
});
```

This code will toggle the visibility of the 2 divs with the `layer` class whenever you click the `p` with the id `button`.